# Append data and display html table

Tags: php

I have some data set. I want to arrange data like this:

[image: table1]

My code displays result like this:

[image: table2].

How can I fix this. This is my code:

```
<?php
echo "<tr><th></th><th>Control</th><th>Sub 1</th><th>Sub2</th></tr>";
    $i=0;
    $PrevIssoff=0;
    $sql="SELECT `code`, `name`,`type` 
            FROM `testdate` 
            WHERE `code`='11111'
            ORDER BY `code` ASC, `type` ASC ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $frm=$row['code'];
        if ($frm != $PrevIssoff && $row['type']==0)
            {
            $i=$i+1;
            $PrevIssoff=$frm;           
            echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>$row[name]</td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
            }   
        else if($row['type']==1 )
            {
            echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td>$row[name]</td><td></td></tr>";
            }
        else if ($row['type']==2)
            {
            echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>$row[name]</td></tr>";
            }
    }

    echo"</table>";
?>
```

**Database table structure** - testdate

[databasetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEmrA.png)

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_*` methods.

Comment: what do you have in the DB? I mean what is the result of the SQL query?

Comment: I update database table structure for the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your data needs to be normalized. There should be a way to write a database query to skip this step if you look hard enough.

Walkthrough each row in the *while loop*, building a close representation for it an array.

```
$dataTable = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $numRows = count($dataTable);
  $lastRowIndex = $numRows == 0 ? 0 : $numRows-1;

  if($numRows == 0) {
     $dataTable[] = [];
  }

  if(count($dataTable[$lastRowIndex]) == 3) {
     $dataTable[] = [];
     $lastRowIndex += 1;
  }

  $type = $row['type'];
  $dataTable[$lastRowIndex][$type] = $row['name'];
}
```

Then make your `$rowsMarkup` which can be readily concatenated with the table heading.

```
$rowsMarkup = array_map(function($row) {
  return '<tr>'.
         '<td>'.$row[0] .'</td>'.
         '<td>'.$row[1] .'</td>'.
         '<td>'.$row[2] .'</td>'.
         '</tr>';
  }, 
  $dataTable
);
```

Comment: When it return values gave error called Notice: Undefined offset: 1